# websocket listener in jmeter

Tags: websocket, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I am testing websocket server using JMeter.

With several times of trial and errors, I could run test successfully.
But I am still unable to see the response properly.

For example,
I made my server to return some specific response, when it receives the request.
However in results listener, sometimes proper response is found, 
but sometimes just request string is found.

I used [JMeter plugin of Kawasima](https://github.com/kawasima/jmeter-websocket)
and added View Results Tree listener.

If I miss something, kindly let me know how to see the correct results.
I already checked the packets, server and jmeter properly communicated each other.

Thanks in advance.
Dongkyoung.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check your play with different values of response timeout in Jmeter. I had the same issue setting different values changes the time of response.

Hope it helps.

[image]